# Is it possible to post to facebook groups acting as page using meta graph api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to post in facebook groups from a page I own programmatically.

I tried finding docs for it. But the docs for facebook graph api is quite confusing to me. I am not sure if its possible or not.
I just want to know if its possible to post to groups as page using graph api.

Comment: Looks like it is possible [but you need the right permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v16.0/group).